# Printing floats and strings in one line

Tags: printing

In trying to run the following code to print floats and strings on same line i get the error that: "Can't convert 'float' object to str implicitly"

```
hours_worked = float(input ("Enter number of hours worked:"))
hourly_rate = float(input ("Enter hourly rate:"))
compute = hours_worked * hourly_rate

overtime = hours_worked - 40
overtime_rate = 1.5*hourly_rate

Total = overtime * overtime_rate + 40*hourly_rate

if hours_worked <= 40:
print ('You worked' + hours_worked + 'and your pay is' + compute)
else:
print ('You worked' + hours_worked + 'and your pay is' + Total)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing this is Python 3, but since it isn't tagged with a language that is my best guess.

You just need to cast hours_worked and compute back into the string type from the float type, like so:

```
print ('You worked' + str(hours_worked) + 'and your pay is' + str(compute))
```

Comment: Also, I hope StackOverflow screwed up your formatting and your original code isn't like that. The two prints won't work unless they are indented from the if and else.

Comment: alternatively, you could write it like this and not have to cast types: `print("You worked", hours_worked, "and your pay is", compute)`